# Issue using step (control flow library) and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, control-flow

If I query for all the documents in a collection the normal way, I have no issues: https://gist.github.com/2562954. The output of this is

```
found docs []
```

However, if I introduce Step (https://github.com/creationix/step), then the output is not an array of documents: https://gist.github.com/2562852. The output of this is:

```
found docs { options: { populate: {} },
  safe: undefined,
  _conditions: {},
  op: 'find',
  model: [Function: Model] }
```

what the heck is going on here? I'd really like to use a control-flow library with mongoose but this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have a similar Step function working.

Note: I don't know if this is what's causing the problem, but when you do this in coffeescript, it adds "return" before `models.Foobar.find({}).run(this);`

```
step(
  function getFoobar() {
    models.Foobar.find({}).run(this);
  }, function (err, docs) {
    console.log('found docs', docs);
    console.log('disconnecting');
    return mongoose.disconnect(this);
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    return console.log('disconnected');
});
```